Display a multiselect dropdown on flutter
I'm new on Flutter, and i'm trying to do a simple thing: have a selection list with multi choices.
I'm a web developer and this is a native feature usually, but i discovered that's not the case in Flutter.
I've tried to find a good plugin for that, and discovered animated_custom_dropdown.
My problem is that the dropdown doesn't save any choice. As i'm new on Flutter, i think i've some context/state problem, but I can't figure out which one. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Choice is not saved
Could someone help me understand or provide a link or example that would help me?
If you know of a better library for simply having a multi-selection dropdown from a future, I'd be interested too!
Thanks in advance!
My current code is basically this:
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen>
    with AfterLayoutMixin<HomeScreen> {
  final SkillRepository _skillRepository = injector.get();

  // ...
  List<Skill> _selectedSkills = [];

  // ...
  Future<List<Skill>> _getSkills() async {
    return await _skillRepository.retrieveAll();
  }
  // ...
    FutureBuilder(
        future: _getSkills(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return CustomDropdown<Skill>.multiSelect(
                hintText: 'Compétences',
                items: snapshot.data.toList(),
                onListChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                  log('changing value to: $value');
                      _selectedSkills = value;
                    }));
          } else {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        }),

UPDATE
In fact, when i replace snapshot.data.toList() by a fixed list, it works like a charm.
ie:
  List<Job> jobItems = [
    const Job('Developer', Icons.developer_mode),
    const Job('Designer', Icons.design_services),
    const Job('Consultant', Icons.account_balance),
    const Job('Student', Icons.school),
  ];

  // ...

    return CustomDropdown<Job>.multiSelect(
        hintText: 'Compétences',
        items: jobItems,
        onListChanged: (value) => setState(() {
          log('changing value to: $value');
              // _selectedSkills = value;
            }));


It works, i can close/reopen the list and checks are keeped.
But when i use snapshot.data.toList() ... no.
Can someone explain to me this mystery and give me some clues to use my FutureBuilder result ?
Thanks !

You must add Controller property to control the selected item
Here's the doc, check the 4th property
animated_custom_dropdown library api doc

Thanks for your reply, but i don't understand really it. When i read doc examples (with or without controllers), controllers are not used to add selection, but more for clearing selection or this kind of things.
In their example, onListChanged do "nothing" and i still can check any checkbox and the result is saved when i close/reopen the list.
I tried to  add  final _skillsController = MultiSelectController<Skill>([]);  and the property multiSelectController but i don't see what to do more. Can you provide me more details ? Thanks !
